# What's the difference between "The Greenford team have" and "The Greenford team has"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, collective-nouns

> The Greenford team **have** completed the installation and hopes that word will soon get around about this life-saving equipment

AND

> The Greenford team **has** completed the installation and hopes that word will soon get around about this...

Answer (score 1):

Uncountable nouns like committee, team etc are sometimes treated as singular and sometimes plural.

> **The Greenford team have completed the installation and hope but not hopes that--------------**
>
> **or The Greenford team has completed and hopes that---------**

You should consistently treat such nouns either singular or plural depending on the context.

There is no difference in meaning between the two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difference between American and British English. In American English, a collective noun (that is, a noun like *team* or *army* referring to a group of people) is generally treated as a singular for the purpose of verb conjugation, whereas in British English it is often treated as a plural. Elvis Costello (Irish) famously sang

> Oliver's army are on their way

which sounds a little strange to our American ears!

There are some other nice examples of this and other grammatical differences between the English dialects here:
http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/grammar-reference/american-english-vs-british-english/differences-in-american-and-british-english-grammar-article/152820.article

Answer (score 0):

Team is a group of persons. In your Sentence you are referring to one team i.e. Greenford team hence you should use **has**. If you were talking about teams the you would have used **Have**.

To summarized **Has** is used with singular subject He, She, it and **have** is used for plural We, they etc.

Comment: This may be good advice for American English, but is simply wrong for British English, where collectives such as "team" can take singular or plural verbs.